# How to create a subquery using criteria Api

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql, criteria-api

I try do the folow JPQL clause to criteria Api

```
 SELECT new ProductDTOOut(p.id,p.name, 
    (SELECT pr.price FROM Price pr WHERE pr.product.id = p.id and pr.company.id = :companyId) ) 
    FROM Product p
```

without success,
how can I do it ?

tnx advanced

Answer (score 0):

I know solve my problem follow answer :

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ProductDTOOut> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(ProductDTOOut.class);

// create query 
Root<Product> rootFrom = criteriaQuery.from(Product.class);

// creating subquery   
Subquery<Double> subquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Double.class);
Root<Price>  subqueryRoot  = subquery.from(Price.class);
subquery.select(subqueryRoot.get(Price_.PRICE));

subquery.where(
 cb.equal(rootFrom.get(Product_.ID), 
   subqueryRoot.get(Price_.PRODUCT).get(Product_.ID)),
 cb.equal(
   subqueryRoot.get(Price_.COMPANY).get(Company_.ID), companyId));      


criteriaQuery.select(cb.construct(ProductDTOOut.class, 
        rootFrom.get(Product_.ID),
        rootFrom.get(Product_.NAME),
        subquery // here put subquery 
        ));

TypedQuery<ProductDTOOut> query = manager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

return query.getResultList();
```

I hope that I helped someone with the same question.